# I'm trying to count and print song file names using awk as following

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, awk

```
RANK  NAME                    BAND  YEAR   GENERE  DOMESTIC/INTERNATIONAL   
206:Reach Out, I'll Be There:The Four Tops:1978:Pop:3/2         
207:Bye Bye Love:The Everly Brothers:1950:Classic:3/2     
208:Gloria:Them:1965:Classic:1/1      
209:In My Room:The Beach Boys:1985:Classic:5/7  
210:96 Tears:? & the Mysterians:1964:Classic:20/15     
211:Caroline, No:The Beach Boys:1975:Classic:5/7   
212:1999:Prince:1958:Classic:5/7       
213:Your Cheatin' Heart:Hank Williams:1988:Soul:7/6
```

(1) I tried to print a list of Rank, performers and songs with new header so I tried:

```
nawk  'BEGIN { FS=":" 
printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", "RANK", "PERFORMER","SONG"
print "=====================================================================\n"}
{printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", $1, $3, $2}' songs
```

but the output still have the default header under the line so how i remove the first line under the new header?

(2)I need to count the number of songs from each type of Genre and report totals of each genre
Desired output is example:

```
classic 10
R&B 5
Soul 9 etc..
```

I tried but failed to get the desired output:

```
awk '{count+$5} END {print $5}' songs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must skip the first line:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" 
printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", "RANK", "PERFORMER","SONG"
print "=====================================================================\n"} 
FNR==1{next}{printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", $1, $3, $2}' songs
```

If you don't mind the order of output, try:

```
$ awk -F':' 'FNR==1{next}{a[$5]+=1} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' songs
Soul 1
Classic 6
Pop 1
```

Comment: Thank you your commands did work successfully ... I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Intermd11: My answer to second question seems wrong, what is the number of songs in your input?

Comment: it did work successfully. output returned without the first line. I have 500 songs in the file

Comment: RANK       PERFORMER                           SONG
=====================================================================

1          Bob Dylan                           Like a Rolling Stone
2          The Rolling Stones                  (I Can't Get No) Satisfaction
3          John Lennon                         Imagine

Comment: @Intermd11: You want `count the number of songs from each type of Genre and report totals of each genre`, is my second answer right?

Comment: `FNR==1{next}{a[$5]+=1}` can be written in a more `awkish` way as `NR>1{a[$5]+=1}`.

Comment: @JS웃: Yeap, my answer is aim to the clarity for the OP.

Comment: and how to print all lines up to a particular song and 5 more songs after that?

Comment: @Intermd11: Do you mean you want to print all lines before the song X, then 5 songs after X? And you don't know the number of X, just its name?